# What should I consider when connecting a PHP app to MSSQL over VPN?

Tags: php, sql-server, centos, vpn

So my understanding so far is:

1. Install CLI VPN client on my Centos server
2. Open VPN connection to remote IIS server
3. Connect to MSSQL in PHP as normal

I'm concerned about

1. Latency: How much should I expect? Will it vary wildly?  Will it "break my application"?
2. Closed connection: Should I expect my connection to just stay open?  Is reopening it in PHP trivial/fast enough?
3. VPN client configuration: Is this going to extremely difficult?  Are there more server settings that need changing besides opening a port?
4. Connecting to DB in PHP: Are there special steps I must take because it's over a VPN?

Other info: this connection is only used by ONE feature on the site (find a local agent) and I don't expect an average user to use that feature more than 1-2 times per visit.

Perhaps this is better as a wiki; I have not found a good article on this subject and the feedback I've gotten about running a webapp DB connection over VPN has been decidedly mixed.  Could someone with experience in this task give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any other way you could do it? SSL perhaps? Nevertheless, my view on the subject.

> Latency: How much should I expect? Will it vary wildly? Will it "break my application"?

Depends on the connection itself and some various factors. For example, we have an OpenVPN connection between our two offices running 24/7, even during high peaks (heavy P2P traffic, don't ask :) the connection is stable and not much latency is observed. The only problem we are experiencing from time to time are ISP issues. When one goes down, work stops for one side. You need to take it into account and implement some sort of fail safe mechanism. If not, your application will "break".

> Closed connection: Should I expect my connection to just stay open? Is reopening it in PHP trivial/fast enough?

I don't recommend PHP application handling VPN connection, it should focus on making sure business logic works properly and leave all connection handling on the networking/server. If you are to put all this logic into application and if VPN connection changes, you will need to rewrite it. Call me lazy, but I like abstraction :)

> VPN client configuration: Is this going to extremely difficult? Are there more server settings that need changing besides opening a port?

Hard to answer this one as there is no information on the VPN client/server used, nor any VPN server configuration. It can be as easy as opening the port or as hard as running a marathon without any prior practice.

> Connecting to DB in PHP: Are there special steps I must take because it's over a VPN?

You shouldn't, just make sure DB is accessible once connected. You will pro

Comment: thank you David.  Re: reopening connection, I just mean "connect to DB, if that fails execute the shell command to initiate a new VPN connection then attempt to connect to the DB again."  Is there an application or utility you'd recommend to monitor a VPN connection and keep it open?

Comment: You should connect to DB only, not opening VPN connection in the PHP app itself. It's important to keep these two layers separated, unless you really want to merge them together for some reason. I have done both in past years, and I prefer having them separated, not allowing PHP to handle it "magically". We are using Nagios (http://www.nagios.org/) to monitor all services and servers, works fine so far :)

Comment: would using SSL achieve the same end of "secure/password protected" connection?